# Try-except, IndexError, Alternativas para solucionar o erro

Tags: python, try-catch

Estou com um trabalho da faculdade pra fazer, de certo modo eu terminei ele, mas com umas gambiarras que queria ajeitar e deixar o código menos confuso e etc.

Funcionamento do programa:

Basicamente ele cria uma tela 600x400 com um `x` número de bolas (esse número é passado por parâmetro da função de cria as bolas) andando pela janela, quando batem nas bordas elas tomam outra trajetória de forma que sempre fiquem na tela.

**Explicação das funções:**

- `criaBola`: Coloca as informações como `tag`, `x`, `y` e aceleração vertical/horizontal;
- `criaBolas`: Quando o programa é iniciado ele espalha as bolas aleatoriamente pela tela, ao longo do programa essa função é usado para fazer as bolas andarem pela tela;
- `verificaBolasArea`: Verifica se onde foi clicado com o mouse existe uma bola, se existir retorna o index da lista;
- `removeBola`: Apaga a bola da tela, essa função é usada tanto pra fazer as bolas andarem tanto para 'estourar' elas;
- `moveBola`: Esse é o coração do programa, faz as bolas mudarem de direção, passa os index da lista pras demais funções, etc;

**Parte que eu preciso de ajuda:**

Na função `moveBola` eu precisei colocar um *try-except* para `IndexError`, o que acontecia é quando eu iniciava o programa tudo funcionava perfeitamente, eu clicava em algumas bolas e elas iam estourando como previsto, mas sempre que chegava na última bola o programa dava erro "*IndexError: list index out of range*"; esse erro também acontecia vez ou outra com as outras bolas sem ser a última. Esse foi o único jeito que eu consegui fazer o programa rodar sem dar erro, mas queria saber se há mais alternativas de como solucionar esse tipo de problema.

```
from Tkinter import *
import random, time

largura = 600
altura = 400
diametro = 50
bola = ['', 0, 0, 0, 0]
bolas = []



def randPos():
    pos = [0,0]
    pos[0] = random.randint(1, (largura - diametro))
    pos[1] = random.randint(1, (altura - diametro))
    return pos


def randCor():
    R = random.randint(100, 255)
    G = random.randint(100, 255)
    B = random.randint(100, 255)
    cor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (R,G,B)
    return cor


def criaBola(id, novaBola):
    if novaBola == True:
        posr = randPos()
        bolas[id][1] = posr[0]
        bolas[id][2] = posr[1]
    tela.create_oval(bolas[id][1], bolas[id][2], bolas[id][1] + diametro, bolas[id][2] + diametro, fill=randCor(), tags=bolas[id][0])
    tela.update()
    print 'bola[index:{}]'.format(bolas.index(bolas[id])),bolas[id][0], randCor(), "POS: X:{} Y:{}".format(bolas[id][1], bolas[id][2])

def criaBolas(quantidade):
    for n in range(quantidade):
        print "CRIA BOLAS INDICE N ", n
        bola[0] = ('bola{}'.format(n))
        bola[3] = 10
        bola[4] = 10
        bolas.append(bola[:])
        print bolas
        criaBola(n, True)
    print(bolas)

def removeBola(idBolaList, idBolaTela):
    print "REMOVENDO BOLA[{}]".format(idBolaTela)
    print type(idBolaList)
    if idBolaList == 999:
        print 'REMOVENDO BOLA PARA ATUALIZACAO DE COORDENADAS'
    else:
        print "PRINTANDO BOLA A SER APAGADA IDBOLALIST", idBolaList, idBolaTela
        bolas.pop(idBolaList)
    tela.delete(idBolaTela)

t = Tk()
tela = Canvas(t, width=largura, height=altura)
tela.pack()

def verificaBolasArea(px1, py1):
    for ii in range(len(bolas)):
        if (bolas[ii][1] <= px1) and (px1 <= (bolas[ii][1]+diametro)) and (bolas[ii][2] <= py1) and (py1 <= (bolas[ii][2] + diametro)):
            print 'O mouse clicou dentro da bola\nA bola[{}] esta nas coordenadas ({},{}) - (X,Y)'.format(bolas[ii][0],bolas[ii][1], bolas[ii][2])
            r = [bolas.index(bolas[ii]), bolas[ii][0]]
            return r
        else:
            print 'bola nao encontrada'

def motion(event):
    print 'tamanho lista:',len(bolas)
    mx, my = event.x, event.y
    r = verificaBolasArea(mx, my)
    removeBola(r[0], r[1])
    print "--->uma bola foi removida", bolas
    print('{}, {}'.format(mx, my))
t.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', motion)

def encerra(event):
    t.destroy()
t.bind('<ButtonRelease-3>', encerra)


def attPos(id):
    print "ATTPOS ID PASSADO ",id, bolas[id][0]
    print bolas
    bolas[id][1] += bolas[id][3]
    bolas[id][2] += bolas[id][4]

def moveBola(idBola = []):
    i=0
    while i>-1:
        try:
            while i<=len(bolas):
                print "WHILE I MOVE BOLAS:" ,i
                index = idBola.index(idBola[i])
                if ((bolas[i][1]+diametro) > largura) or (bolas[i][1] < 0):
                    bolas[i][3] *= -1
                if ((bolas[i][2]+diametro) > altura) or (bolas[i][2] < 0):
                    bolas[i][4] *= -1
                time.sleep(0.0299)
                tela.update()
                print "******************",index
                print len(bolas), bolas, index
                removeBola(999, idBola[i][0])
                attPos(index)
                criaBola(index, False)
                i+=1
                if i == len(bolas):
                    i=0
        except IndexError:
            if len(bolas) <= 0:
                i=-1
                tela.create_text(largura / 2, altura /2, text="PARANBENS! VOCE ESTOUROU TODAS AS BOLAS.\nClique com o botao direito do mouse para fechar o programa.", font=("Arial Black", "12"), tags='Fim', fill='red')
            else:
                i=0
            print len(bolas)*100

criaBolas(10)
moveBola(bolas)

t.mainloop()
```

Comment: Não precisa dizer que é trabalho da faculdade, isso não ajuda em nada. Vá direto ao ponto.

Answer (score 1):

O `len` retorna um valor que começa a partir do 1, e não do 0. Porém, a contagem das posições começa a partir do 0.

```
while i<=len(bolas):
```

Vamos supor que o `len(bolas)` é igual a 10:
As posições das bolas são de 0 à 9, o que fecha 10 números (valor de len), o i começa em 0 e vai até 10 (pois `while i<=len(bolas)`), porém, o array não vai até a posição 10, e sim até a 9.

Creio que trocar `while i<=len(bolas):` por `while i<len(bolas):` irá resolver seu problema, não necessitando assim de try/except.